# C++ and OpenCV: Issue Converting Image to grayscale

Tags: c++, opencv, rgb, grayscale

Here is my code. It's pretty simple.

```
Mat image  = imread("filename.png");

imshow("image", image);
waitKey();

//Image looks great.

Mat image_gray;
image.convertTo(image_gray, CV_RGB2GRAY);

imshow("image", image_gray);
waitKey();
```

But when I call the `image.convertTo(image_gray, CV_RGB2GRAY);` line, I get the following error message:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (func != 0) in unknown function, file ..\..\..\sr
c\opencv\modules\core\src\convert.cpp, line 1020
```

Using OpenCV 2.4.3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The method [`convertTo`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?#void%20Mat%3a%3aconvertTo%28OutputArray%20m,%20int%20rtype,%20double%20alpha,%20double%20beta%29%20const) does not do color conversion.

If you want to convert from BGR to GRAY you can use the function [cvtColor](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?#void%20cvtColor%28InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20int%20code,%20int%20dstCn%29):

```
Mat image_gray;
cvtColor(image, image_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
```

Comment: I should have known that (facepalm). Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome :) By the way: you can load an image directly in grayscale if you want to using this: `Mat image_gray = imread("filename.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);`

Comment: @Jason... If you got a satisfactory answer, you may consider accepting one.

Answer (score 0):

The function [`cv::Mat::convertTo`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-convertto) is not for color conversion. It is for type conversion. The destination image should have same size and number of channels as the source image.

To convert from RGB to Gray, use the function [`cv::cvtColor`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#cvtcolor).

```
cv::cvtColor(image,image_gray,CV_RGB2GRAY);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to acquire video (e.g. from a webcam) in Grayscale, you can also set the saturation of the video feed to zero. (Ex. in Python syntax)

```
 capture = cv.CaptureFromCAM(camera_index)
```

`...`
`cv.SetCaptureProperty(capture, cv.CV_CAP_PROP_SATURATION,0)`

Answer (score 0):

**image.convertTo(image_gray, CV_RGB2GRAY);**
This's wrong.Correct one is,

```
 Mat gray_image;
 cvtColor(image, gray_image, CV_BGR2GRAY);
```

Try this.